# Mysql: select all without column repeat

Tags: mysql, distinct

i want select all columns but without repeat column store (sorry for my bad english)
code mysql :

```
SELECT * FROM store order by views DESC
```

[image]

that's the resultat i want

[image]

Comment: Both images are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not realy clear what you want, but try the following:

```
select * from store s1 join (
    SELECT store, max(views) as views FROM store group by store ) s2 on s1.store = s2.store and s1.views = s2.views 
order by s1.views DESC
```

Comment: @Bensalem Sorry have correted it